# Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

Tags: javascript

I am using this script in Google Tag Manager as a Custom HTML tag to replace button-click URLs. I am getting this error in Chrome - **Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL**

**Objective**

When a user lands on the site, he lands on `/example?gclid=898`, when he clicks on the button, I want to extract the cookie value and append it to the URL via search params API. The final URL will look something like this - `/example?gclid=898&client_id=123`

**The below code is used in Custom HTML Tag in Google Tag Manager**.

```
<script>

(function () {
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*=example]');

links.forEach(function(link) {

var original = link.getAttribute('href');      
console.log(original);

var url = new URL(original);
console.log('This is new URL :' + url);  

url.searchParams.append('client_id',{{Read Cookie Value}});
console.log(url);
  
link.setAttribute('href', url);
              
 })

}) ();
  
</script>
```

This is the error I get on the console:

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL**

[image: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL]

Is there a way to fix this? It seems doesn't seem to recognize the new construct URL.

Comment: What's the value of `original` that fails…?

Comment: I have added an image. The original value is /example?gclid_id=786. So I want to replace the link with cookie value through search params API. So, the final link will be /lets-talk?gclid_id=786&client_id=123 with the appended value.

Comment: Please post the output in *Console* as text here; a picture of the Sources tab is uninteresting.

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The original value is `/example?gclid_id=786`.

The `URL` constructor only works for relative URLs, if you provide a `base` as second argument.

But you can avoid this problem, if you read the actual property value - and not the attribute.

```
var original = link.getAttribute('href');
```

this gets you the content of the attribute, as it was written in the HTML code. If you use

```
var original = link.href;
```

instead, you should get an absolute URL, that the `URL()` constructor will accept directly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/href:

> The HTMLAnchorElement.href property is a stringifier that returns a string containing the whole URL

Comment: So this is the base - https://example.com/lets-talk as a second argument.

Answer (score 2):

you need `base`.

> A string or any other object with a stringifier — including, for example, an  or  element — that represents an absolute or relative URL. If url is a relative URL, base is required, and will be used as the base URL. If url is an absolute URL, a given base will be ignored.

[docs/Web/API/URL/URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)